# Determing noise type and level of noise

Tags: regression, white-noise

**Context**

I have a set of data that was collected from several inertial measurement units (orientation and acceleration data). I want to determine to what extent an inference method degrades when the data becomes noisy (or, should I say "noisier").

**Questions**

How do I determine what type of noise to use? Is there a way in which I can find this out from the data itself?

What range of noise levels would be appropriate for testing the inference method's robustness? My guess is that it would depend on the answer to the question: "how noisy would you expect the environment/system to get"? Again, given only the collected data, what is the best approach in determining these levels?

Comment: Strangely enough, for IMUs, sometimes noise can *improve* your measurements and inferences! (**Think**: dithering.) Can you give more details on the types of signals you're trying to measure, e.g., sampling rate, frequencies of interest, etc.?

Comment: There were 5 IMUs that streamed data via a Bluetooth link. The maximum possible sampling frequency depended on this link. In the given setup, a sampling frequency of 50Hz was used.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Is that 50Hz per channel? Can you describe the error further? Is this primarily vibration/thermal-noise error or are you concerned about drift in an estimate of position, say, due to nonidealities in numerical double integration? What are your frequencies of interest? What is your dynamic range, e.g., in LSBs? What is your error standard deviation?